# Highstock rendering errors in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, highcharts

I have a chart made using the Highcharts library, which can be found here: http://meteotoren.nl/meteodata/windsnelheid.php

On non-internet-explorer browsers this chart works perfectly, but on internet explorer I get weird rendering issues, like can be seen [image: here]

Note how when moving the mouse over the chart, the tooltip does not correctly render.

I have tried using different version of jQuery and of the Highstock library, both locally hosted and hosted in their own code repository / Google Code, all to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is known issue, and for IE < 9 we advice to disable tooltip's [animation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.animation)

Comment: Disabling the animation does not seem to make any difference, the rendering issues still occur. Of course disabling the tooltip entirely solves the issue, but is this the only solution?

Comment: Interesting, are you sure you have latest Highcharts? Try this: `http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js`

Comment: I do indeed have the latest version, but whatever version I tried did not seem to make any difference.However, I have managed to find a solution: Apparently, declaring <!doctype html> at the beginning of whatever page you're using a chart on fixes the problem, even WITH animations enabled.